# Убрать желтку рамку у якорной ссылки

Tags: html, css

При переходе на якорную ссылку. Элемент выбранный якорем выделяется желтой рамкой! - Подскажите как ее убрать.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь задействуется `outline`.
Нужно поставить `outline: none`. Возможно на `a:active` или еще как-то загорается - надо смотреть. А можно и оставить как есть, ведь пользователю так удобнее - он видит куда идет переход.

Answer (score 0):

Что-то вида:

```
elem .selected{
   border: none;
}
```

Идентификатор elem сами найдите из кода страницы.

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что outline может быть задействован не только на `a` и не только одном состоянии. К тому же, может создаваться еще и отступ, который в будущем помешает создать правильную обводку. Для решения всех этих проблем советую использовать такую конструкцию:

```
// Remove outline on the forms and links
:active, :hover, :focus {
    outline: 0;
    outline-offset: 0;
}
```